# Cannot build app - wrong reference for framework on a different device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, path

My project was building on my device perfectly fine and then all of the sudden I switched to another device and it started to give me this error.

I've removed derived data, added and removed search paths to and from $(inherited) and from recursive to non-recursive, I just don't know how to source the issue. Here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see, the files exist:

[image]

I just don't know why switching the device prevents them from being found on build. Even if you don't have a solution, I'd appreciate any guidance to a resource where I can learn how to solve issues like these. They happen more often than not and I don't feel I have a clear enough understanding of how things link together. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

**Edit**: As far as my architecture configuration, here's what I have in my project's build settings:

[image]

**Edit #2**: To answer the question below about my build-only architecture, it's as follows:

[image]

Comment: the error says it can't find symbols for `arm64` architecture, may be (this is only an assumption) it's not building for arm64, you wouldn't have seen it if you were testing with a 32bit device before.

Comment: I updated my question with some information regarding my architecture configurations

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Project
Select your Target
Then, go to Build Phases
Open Link Binary With Libraries
Finally, just add + the framework / any other framework.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, here is a screenshot of what I did for your proposed solution http://i.imgur.com/F9LdiTZ.png

Comment: What are your build for active architecture set to? It should be yes.

Comment: I have my app target > Build Settings > "Build Active Architecture Only" set to Yes